# asp.net application is working very slow after wcf service application

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am developing one asp.net application and I am using one WCF service application to get data from database in this application . webconfig configuration of Client application is like this.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
     <wsHttpBinding>
       <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IServicePaymentControllerUIClient"
        closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
        sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
         <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
          enabled="false" />
         <security mode="Message">
           <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
           <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
            algorithmSuite="Default" />
         </security>
       </binding>
     </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
  <client>
   <endpoint address="http://localhost:63796/ServicePaymentControllerUIClient.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IServicePaymentControllerUIClient"
    contract="ServiceReferencePaymentControllerUI.IServicePaymentControllerUIClient"
    name="WSHttpBinding_IServicePaymentControllerUIClient">
    <identity>
     <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
   </endpoint>
  </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

before using WCF Service my asp.net application was pretty fast, but now its loading very slow. 
So I want to know the reason behind it and how can I get rid of this issue ??
How to increase performance of my application ??

Comment: What exactly became slow? Pages load slowly or what? Did you run a profiler?

Comment: application which is using this service. and page load too .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find wrong with your config files.
As you mentioned that your request time out, you should to trace what error is.

I suggest you enable WCF tracing to get detail information, configure trace sources to emit traces and set trace levels, set activity tracing and propagation to support end-to-end trace correlation, and set trace listeners to access traces.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx

Thank you,
Vishal Patel